# want to create push notifications for angular app backend is made in laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

i have my back end made in laravel and front end in angular 5 i want to implement notification system for angular app,

can you please suggest some package for laravel angular push notification system

i have read about one signal, push bullet etc

but they support Laravel only not Laravel and angular

please give me suggestions if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RxJS Subject to implement this in your Angular.

In your service where you update or create  define a property changeDetect like this:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
public changeDetect: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Now 'changeDetect' acts both as Observer and Observable, so you could inform any component about changes being made and subscribe to that change to reflect updated data. In your case the updated data is Notification and you'll have to subscribe to it. In your subscribe, you can have a toaster displaying change made as a Notification.

In your service, in the function where a certain change is made using POST or PUT(Hitting API):

```
this.changeDetect.next(<DataToUpdate/DataToChange>);
```

Now in the component where the Data is rendered subscribe to that change like this:

```
this.changeDetect.subscribe((<DATA>) => {<CALL TO TOASTER TO DISPLAY WHATEVER>});
```

Ofcourse you need to make necessary import here in this component as well.

Though this is not so comprehensive, this might get you started.